# @ManyToOne for a single column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have the following simplified table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE order(
    order_id    INT PRIMARY KEY,
    fk_contact  INT REFERENCES contact(contact_id)
);

CREATE TABLE contact(
    contact_id  INT PRIMARY KEY,
    name        VARCHAR
);
```

In reality, the `contact` table has many more columns which I do not need (or want) in the `Order` entity. I was hoping to add a `contactName` field in the `Order` entity. I have tried `@SecondaryTable`, but that doesn't make sense because the `fk_contact` column is not a PK of `Order`. I could also create a separate class just to hold this `name` field, but I was hoping to have a `String` field in the `Order` class, not a nested entity.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ManyToOne annotation to specific column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38204233/manytoone-annotation-to-specific-column)

Answer (score 0):

the solution to this is [Entity Graphs](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for. I do not want to join to a `Contact` entity, I just want a `contactName` field in the `Order` entity.

Comment: this means you don't want to keep the relation (because most probably the name is not unique), you can then just use Converter
https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters